# Can I differentiate $f(z)= z^2 e^\overline{z}$ with z in complex numbers?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

$\overline{z}$ is the conjugate of $z$.

And $z=x+iy$.

I don't know if it can be differentiated in any point for every complex number $z$.

I've tried to proof if it is differentiable in an exact point. I have separated the real part and the imaginary part and I have tried if the partial derivates are equal or not. But they are equal in an infinite number of points.

So, I don't know what can I try now.

Comment: Is $f(z) = \overline{z}$ entire? Do you know the definition? How would you show whether it is or isn't?

Comment: Do you know the Cauchy-Riemann equations?

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee

$f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$.

I have tried with the Cauchy-Riemann equations, but I got that this is not differentiable in every point. Now I don't know how can I get the points where $f$ is differentiable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(z) = z^2 e^{\overline{z}} = (x+iy)^2 e^{x-iy} = (x^2 -y^2 + 2ixy) e^{x-iy} = e^x(x^2 -y^2 + 2ixy)(\cos y - i \sin y)\\
=e^x[(x^2 - y^2)\cos y + 2xy \sin y] + i e^x[2xy\cos y - (x^2-y^2)\sin y].$$

Then apply the [Cauchy Riemann equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations), with $u(x,y) =e^x[(x^2 - y^2)\cos y + 2xy \sin y]$ and $v(x,y) =  e^x[2xy\cos y - (x^2-y^2)\sin y]$.

This gives you a test of whether $f$ is differentiable.

Comment: I got there, and after applyint the Cauchy Riemann equations I got 2 equations: $x^2cos(y)-y^2cos(y)+2xysin(y)=0$ and $xsin(y)+ycos(x)=0$

Comment: Then you have differentiability exactly when those equations are satisfied. They aren't always: e.g. if $x = 0$, $y = \pi$, then the second one gives $0 - 4 \pi  =0 $ which is obviously false. Thus this gives you a precise characterization of the points at which you have differentiability.